# How to remove all Categorical columns from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

Categorical columns are a great way to save memory RAM in pandas, however there are times in which they just slow down things. Specially after you are passed the stage in which you have a big dataframe and now are working in a subset. For example, it doesn't seem to play that well with printing in Jupyter or using libraries like qgrid.

I basically would like to remove all categorical columns from a dataframe to speed up simple things:

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "a"], 
                   "B": ["a", "b", "c", "a"],
                   "C": [0,3,0,3],
                   "D": [0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3],
                   "F": [0,1,2,3]
                  }
                 )
df["B"] = df["B"].astype('category')
df["C"] = df["C"].astype('category')
df["D"] = df["D"].astype('category')
```

Which results in some columns being Categorical (with different types: int, float, str).

```
df.dtypes
A      object
B    category
C    category
D    category
F       int64
dtype: object
```

Ideally something like:

```
df = df.remove_all_categorical_columns();
```

That would return the original basic types:

```
df.dtypes
A     object
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
F      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to toto's answer but without `df.apply()`.

```
def recover_dtypes(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'category':
            df[col] = df[col].astype(df[col].cat.categories.to_numpy().dtype)
    return df

df1 = recover_dtypes(df)
print(df1.dtypes)
>>>
A     object
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
F      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. The OP's question is to "recover" the original dtype from a category column.

Comment: @R.Zhu I updated to account for recovery and not strictly removal.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the original data type using `df['column'].cat.categories.dtype`. The rest is a matter of going through all the columns using `df['column'].astype(df['column'].cat.categories.dtype)`.

The following would work in your example (and hopefully generic enough for other cases):

```
def uncategorize(col):
    if col.dtype.name == 'category':
        try:
            return col.astype(col.cat.categories.dtype)
        except:
            # In case there is pd.NA (pandas >= 1.0), Int64 should be used instead of int64
            return col.astype(col.cat.categories.dtype.name.title())           
    else:
        return col

df = df.apply(uncategorize, axis=0)
```

Then, you recover your original dtypes.

```
df.dtypes
A     object
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
F      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: As a quick note, you can simply use `df.apply(uncategorize, axis=0)` instead of using the lambda expression.